# How to make soundfile in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer

i wanted to make a code which generates a sound file in wav format. However, i got stuck whet trying to play it. This is what i have done so far:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var buf = new Buffer(176400);
var fileName = "i_write_this_wave.wav";
var fd = fs.openSync(fileName, "w");
buf.writeUInt32BE(0x52494646, 0);
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x24080000, 4);
buf.writeUInt32BE(0x57415645, 8);
buf.writeUInt32BE(0x666d7420, 12);
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x10000000, 16);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x0100, 20);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x0200, 22);
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x22560000, 24);
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x88580100, 28);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x0400, 32);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x1000, 34);
buf.writeUInt32BE(0x64617461, 36);
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x00080000, 40);
var vl = 32000;
var of = 44;
while (of < 176400) {
buf.writeUInt16LE(vl, of);
of = of + 2;
}
fs.writeSync(fd, buf, 0, buf.length);
```

It makes the wav file with right header, etc, but i am not able to play it. I think there is a problem with the buffer size, but what should be the right size of the buffer? If you have any suggestions please here with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `writeUInt16LE` and `writeUInt32LE`. If you want to write the 32-bit integer `0x5622` in little endian, for instance, you should use

```
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x5622, 24);
```

You are reversing every value that you write in little endian, resulting in those appearing in the file in big endian, which is going to result in an invalid file.

For concreteness, here is how I would rewrite your code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var buf = new Buffer(176400);
var fileName = "i_write_this_wave.wav";
var fd = fs.openSync(fileName, "w");
buf.writeUInt32BE(0x52494646, 0);
buf.writeUInt32LE(buf.length-8, 4);
buf.writeUInt32BE(0x57415645, 8);
buf.writeUInt32BE(0x666d7420, 12);
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x10, 16);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x01, 20);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x02, 22);
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x5622, 24);
buf.writeUInt32LE(0x15888, 28);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x04, 32);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x10, 34);
buf.writeUInt32BE(0x64617461, 36);
buf.writeUInt32LE(buf.length-44, 40);
var vl = 32000;
var of = 44;
while (of < 176400) {
    buf.writeUInt16LE(vl, of);
    of = of + 2;
}
fs.writeSync(fd, buf, 0, buf.length);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes a playable soundfile, but i have a few more questions though. When i play it, it makes no sound. First, i thought that changing value of variable vl will make a difference, but why i doesn't affect the sound at all? Also why did you put there variable frequency when you never use it?

Comment: @Roman: Oops, frequency was a mistake, I thought I would use it but I ended up not using it, I'll edit it out. A RIFF WAVE file with format 1 (as you have here) is encoded as [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) data, which means that each value in the file is the intensity at a certain time. Sound waves are formed by varying the intensity, so if you just use a constant value you have no sound. Try: `buf.writeInt16LE(Math.round(Math.sin(of/4*2000/0x5622*Math.PI*2)*16000), of);`, this will generate a tone. 2000 is the frequency (2 KHz), 16000 is the amplitude (1/4 max).

Comment: Okay, from here i believe i can continue on my own, thank you very much, you helped me a lot.